# C++ long double formatting without rounding

Tags: c++, double

I want to show only two decimal places from long double without rounding.

Example:

14.999999 => 14.99

12.501 => 12.50

12.505 => 12.50

There is a problem with some values.

For example this:

Excepted 204969/340 = 602.85

My result 204969/340 = 602.84

Code sample:

```
long long a = 204969;
long long b = 340;
long double final_result = (long double) a / (long double) b;
final_result = ((long long)(final_result * 100) / 100.00);

cout << fixed << setprecision(2) <<final_result;
```

Why?

Comment: This is the nature of fixed-precision representations. If you expect *exact* results -- where it must be precisely 602.85 and you will not accept 602.849999999999, then don't use fixed precision representations! You should not expect a floating point operation to produce the exact result and you should not write code that cannot tolerate microscopic rounding at the last few digits.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `204969/340`, when represented as a double, is not exactly `602.85`, but `602.849999999999999978`, and this value times `100` gives `60284.9999999999999978`, and this value converted to `long long` gives `60284`, and this one divided by `100.00` gives `602.840000000000031832`, this then rounded at a precision of 2 finally prints `602.84`.

I'd do the "times 100" on base of the `long` and finally divide by `100.0`:

```
long double final_result = (a*100/b)/100.00;
```

This then gives `602.850000000000022737`, and rounded to precision 2 prints `602.85`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the nature of binary representations. You are asking for a result in decimal places, but floating-point doesn't *have* decimal places. It has *binary* places, and the two are incommensurable. If you want decimal places, use a decimal radix, i.e. do what it says in your title and *format* the double, into a char buffer, using a mask.

The technique of multiplying and then dividing by 100 *does not work*. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153724/how-to-round-a-number-to-n-decimal-places-in-java/12684082#12684082) for proof.

Answer (score -1):

Probably a discrepancy error related to long double

I tried this code:

```
long long a = 204969;
long long b = 340;

double final_result = (double)(a*100/b)/100;
```

It gives me: 602.85.

If you need that just for typing the result, you could do it without using doubles:

```
 long long result = a*100/b;
 printf ("Result = %ld.%ld\n", result/100, result % 100);
```

Comment: Should the format be `%ld.%02ld` in case the remainder is less than 10?

Answer (score -2):

> Use **floor** function when **final_result** still **long double** so decimal places clear then cast to **long long**

```
  long long a = 204969;
  long long b = 340;
  long double final_result = (long double) a / (long double) b;
  final_result = ((long long)(floor(final_result * 100)) / 100.00);
  cout << fixed << setprecision(2) <<final_result;
```